# Angular's ng-options not displaying default correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm running into an issue with ng-options that I am having difficulty tracking down. I am using an array of strings with ng-options in a select control. It seems to be tracking correctly, but the default month name isn't displaying as the selected value in the dropdown on page load. I've created the following jsfiddle to illustrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/risingfish/ktocfrhn/13/

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('momentTest', []);

myApp.controller('main', function ($scope) {
    $scope.months = moment.months();
    $scope.currentMonth = 7;
});

myApp.run();
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="momentTest" ng-controller="main">
  <div>
    <select name="monthPicker" ng-model="currentMonth" ng-options="idx as month for (idx, month) in months">
    </select>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <div>
    Current month: <span ng-bind="currentMonth"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure it's operator error, but I'm not have much look googling for the answer. Any one have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that the `idx` actually is a `string` (you can see it in generated HTML in the `value` of `option` tag).

Then, to make it work you just need to set the *default* as `string`:

```
$scope.currentMonth = '7';
```

Forked [**`DEMO`**](https://jsfiddle.net/s84qw06x/).

Comment: Sure enough, thank you. I thought I had tested that but apparently not the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following solutions

**Solution 1**

in your html file

`<div  ng-app="momentTest" ng-controller="main"> 
   <div> 
     <select name="monthPicker" ng-model="currentMonth" ng-options="month  for month in months" > </select>

   </div> 
<div>`

in your app.js

`$scope.months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August','September','October','November','December'];
  $scope.currentMonth = $scope.months[0];`

**Solution 2**

in your html file

`<div  ng-app="momentTest" ng-controller="main">
    <select name="monthPicker" ng-model="currentMonth" ng-options="idx as month  for (idx,month) in months" ng-init="currentMonth='0'"> </select>

 </div>`

in your app.js
`$scope.months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August','September','October','November','December'];`